# Child Page templates

Tags: channel-entries, templates, structure, pages

I have just downloaded the latest EE from Ellis Lab today. I am trying to create various child pages, each with a different template. Is this possible? I keep getting the following message:

"An Error Was Encountered
You are not authorized to access this page"

If this message doesnt occur, the parent template is inherited.

Thanks

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Please describe the steps you make in details.

Comment: Hi Yuri, What I was trying to get across was that If I were to create a child page of my Index page, the child page is inheriting the template of the index page. The question I'd like answered, Is this a mistake on my end with the set up or is this how the system works generically.? I should mention that I am using the add-on 'Structure' to create child pages

Answer (score 2):

ExpressionEngine relationships between pages / entries in the core are linear, there is no such thing as a child page.

If you want to have nested URLs, have a look at third-party add-ons, such as Structure.

You may also achieve nested URLs with built-in Pages module, but it's not as visual as Structure

Comment: Can I also add [Navee](http://fromtheoutfit.com/navee) & [Taxonomy](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/taxonomy) to the mix. I've used all three but always seem to go back to Structure.